# Checkcolumn checkchange check always false

Tags: extjs

I have a checkcolumn, there when column value is true and user clicks on it, it changes to false, but on the click when column value is false, and user clicks on it, it remains false, Here is the complete code-

```
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'isDeveloper',
    header: "Developer",
    minWidth: 80,
    align: "center",
    reference: "isdeveloper",
    
    listeners: {
        
        checkchange: function (column, rowIndex, checked, record, e, eOpts) {
            this.up('CheckboxTestSummaryView').getController().onCheckChange(column, rowIndex, checked, record, e, eOpts);
        }
    },
    
    renderer: function (value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        var cssPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix,
            cls = [cssPrefix + 'grid-checkcolumn-c'];
        if (value=="true") {
            cls = (cssPrefix + 'grid-checkcolumn-c-checked');
        }
        return '<div class="' + cls + '" ></div>';
    }
}
```

And in the checkchange event I am doing an AJAX call

```
    onCheckChange: function (column, rowIndex, checked, record, e, eOpts) {
    
    var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("CheckboxTestSummaryView")[0];
    

    record.commit();
    form.getView().refresh();

    var DataToSave = { _id: record.data._id, Name: record.data.Name, isDeveloper: record.data.isDeveloper == 'true' ? true : false }
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '../api/CheckboxTestSummaryView/Save',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            'isDeveloper': JSON.stringify(DataToSave)
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '../api/CheckboxTestSummaryView/GetData?xtype=CheckboxTestSummaryView',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var res = '';
                        if (response) {
                            res = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                            form.store.loadData(res.Data);
                        }

                    }
                })
            }
            form.store.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

But the value of checked always changes to false, for true to false, works perfectly, but for false to true never works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with extjs, you compare with `'true'` it will be false all the time.

Also, renderer makes no sense in `checkcolumn` and what are you trying to do there is just not needed, but also confusing, `cls` can be array or string there, you again comparing with string `"true"`.

Comment: I entered the renderer because without that, the tick and cross cannot be seen, pls help telling the solution , i am new to programming, just did all the code by taking reference from other grids and the internet

Comment: I can't really tell you a solution there, you have basic issues with this. The first one, as I told you, you are doing this: `record.data.isDeveloper == 'true'`. Comparing a boolean with a string, this will be false all the time. Also, you manually sending up a change when tick a checkbox, then on the response you reload your whole dataset. This is just not the way. Please read the docs about stores and proxies, add a rest proxy to your store which is attached to the grid then simply call a `store.sync()` when you want to save.

Comment: Thank you so much, though it was a part of a problem, changed all the string to boolean and it works, sorry, can't upvote, not enough reputation, but thanks from the bottom of my heart :)